# Android App Icon Shortcut Rename

Tags: android, rename, shortcut

Looking to change the name for an app (icon name) with established user base.

Are there any issues that I should foresee that users can face when they download the update?

Specifically worried about problems with launchers not updating the name of the icon properly of giving 'app does not exist or installed' message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android OS will read the manifest which will point to the icon and name to use for the app. It shouldn't cause an issue if your IDE does not complain and you won't hit the 'app does not exist or installed' because the package name will stay the same.

You can test this very easily by installing the old version, and then building (but not running) the new version with the change in app name and/or app shortcut image. Then simulate an update by going into command line or terminal and running

```
adb install -r MyApp.apk
```

This will update the app on your device with your new app name and/or app image but still keep the app database and store preferences - thus simulating an app update.